# change button image on click and show result in iframe, on next button click, return original button to first one

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

I have multiple buttons (as menu) as images on index page. I have rollover image on all of the buttons. 
On click, result is show on iframe in the middle of the page. But i want also that button change and stay changed until next menu button is clicked.

Example for one button:

`<a href="faq.html" target="show" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('faq','','images/faq_y.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/faq_b.jpg" alt="faq" name="faq" width="70" height="70" id="faq" /></a>`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking questions. You did not provide any html or javascript and haven't shown an effort to do this yourself.

Comment: MangleMedia scripts. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways to achieve what you are trying to do. I take it that you are using Dreamweaver. Generally the scripts that come with Dreamweaver are pretty poor and out dated.

For example, instead of using the "roll over" image changing ability that comes with Dreamweaver. You can just use plan old css.

For example if you created an image twice as wide as your button and added both states of your button side by side. By doing that you can now use css to simply move the visible area of your button from one side to the next, or as it will appear from your "normal state" to your "hover state"

Example css:

```
// button normally. Because we specify a width and height that is all that
// will be shown of our background. e.g. Our "normal state"
a.myButton {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:url(images/my-button-sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
}

// This will switch the button to our right side (or our "over state")
a:hover.myButton, a.myButton.active  {
    background:url(images/my-button-sprite.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

In relation to your keeping the hover state over until another menu item is clicked.

Do a Google for "jQuery". It's a set of tools and plugins that use Javascript. JavaScript is what is currently doing the swapping of images for you.

There are 1,000's of tutorial on how to use css and jQuery to get the result you want.

Check out these resources:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/ << CSS is your friend.. Learn it..

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ << this is what will allow you (using the code I have provided) to do what you're trying to do.

But I'm not going to tell you exactly how to do it.. Because that spoils half the fun!